# Is there a reason to use port 25?

Tags: email, tcp, port

I started to work with transactional emails and I see a lot of articles that tell me to avoid port 25 because my email might be blocked.  If that's the case when is port 25 used? I'm currently using Mandrill and they give me the option of using port 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this article. It is a bit old but has details:

http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/technology/7477899.stm

As far as I know many ISPs and hosting services crack down on port 25 to stop abusive spam. Also since botnets generate the majority of spam, ISPs tend to stop users from directly sending emails to servers.